# How do I download en for spacy using conda?

Tags: python, nlp, spacy

I am currently using Windows OS. I have installed Anaconda for creating environments. I have successfully created another environment with python 2.7. I have also installed spacy on that environment using:

`conda install --name myenv -c spacy spacy`

But now I need to download 'en module to run it. On spacy official site they have mentioned the following commands for the same:
`conda install -c conda-forge spacy
python -m spacy download en`

then I activated the 2nd environment using:

```
activate myenv
```

But running the second command(python -m spacy..)it gives me an error:

```
 No module named spacy.__main__; 'spacy' is a package and cannot be
 directly executed
```

Please help me..

Comment: Did you install spacy after creating the virtual environment or before?

Comment: @raj after creating the virtual env

Answer (score 11):

This Solution worked for me:

1. Go to start and right Click on the Anaconda Promt icon
2. Select "Open as Administrator"
3. Type `python -m spacy download en`

It should install the package and also link it. Just typing `python -m spacy download en` didnt work for me since it failed to link the package for some obscure reason

Answer (score 8):

installing spacy package through conda prompt doesn't automatically download lexicons. You have to specifically download the lexicons using the following command:

```
conda$python -m spacy download en
```

And from your python code you should reference it as below:

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('en')
```

Another alternative is you can download more specific models as below:

```
# most relevant model for your spacy installation
python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm

# exact model version (doesn't create shortcut link)
python -m spacy download en_core_web_sm-2.0.0 --direct
```

And in your python code, you would do like below:

```
import en_core_web_sm
nlp = en_core_web_sm.load()
```

Comment: On running that command it gives me this error: No module named spacy.__main__; 'spacy' is a package and cannot be
 directly executed

Answer (score 4):

in jupyter notebook type this
it worked for me

```
import spacy
from spacy.cli import download
print(download('en'))
```

wait for some time it will show download completed
I hope it works for you!